# Missing projects information from the OWASP Secure Coding Practices

Tags: security, owasp, application-security

When I found the [OWASP Secure Coding Practices Guide](https://www.owasp.org/images/0/08/OWASP_SCP_Quick_Reference_Guide_v2.pdf), I felt like I had found a hidden gem. The information in the checklist format is great. Although I was disappointed to see that links pointed to multiple other external projects is not found and the artifacts for them just do not exist. So pointing it here hoping anyone has more information on them.

- Implement a secure software development lifecycle - [OWASP CLASP Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_CLASP_Project): Returns page has been deleted
- [ESAPI for Php](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API#tab=PHP) link on [OWASP Enterprise Security API](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API) project returns nothing

I am unsure how to find or access these.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around I did find [ESAPI Python Readme](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI_Python_Readme).

As for the OWASP CLASP Project, it looks like that project has been removed due to inactivity (these projects are maintained by volunteers) and now outdate/wrong information.

Depending on what you are looking for, I suggest look at the [OWASP Project Inventory](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Project#tab=Project_Inventory).  This lists out all of OWASP's projects.

Answer (score 0):

The CLASP project is no longer supported. It has been supersed by the OpenSAMM (http://www.opensamm.org) project who can give you all the things to setup a good and efficent SSDLC (Secure Software Development Live Cycle).

Anyways, as the OWASP projects are movings, i suggest you to point all the time to the home page to have a good and updated view